# Service Layer Pattern: Business logic that spans multiple services

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service-layer

In developing an n-tier application, I seem to have hit a scenario where one service say service A needs to consume a method in service B.  I do not want to duplicate logic but it does not seem like I should not have services calling one another either.  What is the best way to handle this situation without violating any rules?  I am thinking about taking the common method out of service B and add to another class and have both services inherit from this class.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection.

Service A expects a well defined service to be injected into it that is expressed with an interface. This way Service B can be injected as well as any other service implementing the same contract.

Comment: Am I violating that with the approach I am thinking of doing above?

Comment: DI is perfectly ok. On the other hand, inheritance could hurt as it introduces high coupling.

Comment: What would a more efficient approach be?

Comment: I don't see any approach more efficient than DI here.